# Transferring data throgh an Intent and on button click go to a different activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, buttonclick, data-transfer

I've 3 activities in my android application (Android Studio), activity1 sends data through intent to activity2 and when a button of activity1 is pressed activity3 should launch. How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please Give more information about it

Comment: Activity1- EditText value should be transferred to Activity2 on Button click. And on Button Click, the Activity3 should launch.
Activity2- It has to receive data from Activity1

Answer (score 0):

You can launch New Activity and send data. Call it from the button click.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityThree.class);
intent.putExtra("key", "value"); //Optional parameters
startActivity(intent);
```

For the above mixup that you want to achieve, i will suggest you to save your data some where else (shared preference etc). Call Activity3 on button click. And whenever you want to access data from Activity2. You can access it from shared preference.

Comment: Here, the data will be passed to Activity3. I want to pass it to Activity2 and it has to launch Activity3

Comment: Then it's `ActivityTwo.this`

Answer (score 0):

In the first activity button click:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
intent.putExtra("key", "value"); //Optional parameters
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the second activity use(in onCreate):

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
String s=intent.getStringExtra("key","DefaultValue");
```

then in the button click from second activity write:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityTwo.this, ActivityThree.class);
intent.putExtra("key1", s); //Optional parameters
startActivity(intent);
```

and finally in activityThree write:

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
String s=intent.getStringExtra("key1","DefaultValue");
```